# How to embed an image from local in a plantUML sequence diagram?

Tags: syntax-error, ubuntu-18.04, sequence-diagram, plantuml, creole

Is it possible to embed images (other than sprites) from local machine in a PlantUML sequence diagram. Tried to insert a sequence code within the PlantUML Creole after ';' and before ':',but got syntax error.  Is there a way to insert images into the sequence diagram.

Comment: `;` and `:` are in activity diagrams, but you tagged sequence-diagrams. Can you please post code of what exactly you were trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

It should work. I'm not on Ubuntu, but if I use the VSCode PlantUML plug-in in Windows, and create a file `test.puml`:

```
@startuml test

participant "<img:blah.png{scale=0.5}>" as blah
blah -> A : Hello

@enduml
```

and I save it in the same directory as `blah.png` I get a result as expected:

[image]